# Pyqt Dialog from Main Window closes only after OK button pressed twice

Tags: pyqt

I have a Main Window with some sliders and spinbox whose value are received from another Edit dialog. All the .ui files have been converted by pyuic4 and are being used in Main program. The Edit Dialog consist of sliders and spinbox with OK and Cancel button. The data from Dialog is received in the Main Window.

Main Program code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from Test_MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from dialogParameters2 import Ui_DialogParameters2


class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # python 3 version
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.action_Shutdown.triggered.connect(lambda: self.close_MyWindow())
        self.action_Edit.triggered.connect(self.dialogParametersOpen)       



    def updateSpeedValue(self):
        scaledValue = float(self.hSliderSpeed.value()) / 10  # type: float
        # self.lblSpeedValue.setText(str(self.hSliderSpeed.value()))
        print(scaledValue, type(scaledValue))
        self.lblSpeedValue.setText(str(scaledValue))


    def dialogParametersOpen(self):
        dialogParameters = CreateParameterDialog()

        # dialogParameters.show()
        if dialogParameters.exec_():
            print("Speed: %s, Rounds: %s, Overlap: %s " % (str(dialogParameters.lblSpeedValue.text()), \
                                                           str(dialogParameters.spinBoxRounds.value()),
                                                           str(dialogParameters.lblOverlapValue.text())))
            self.hSliderSpeed.setValue(dialogParameters.hSliderSpeed.value())
            self.spinBoxRounds.setValue(dialogParameters.spinBoxRounds.value())
            self.hSliderOverlapDeg.setValue(dialogParameters.hSliderOverlap.value())
        print('Dialog Completed with ' + str(dialogParameters.exec_()))

    def close_MyWindow(self):
        print("Window Closed")
        # sys.exit()


class CreateAboutDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DialogAbout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Python2 version
        # super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


class CreateParameterDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_DialogParameters2):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Python2 version
        # super(self.__class__,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        sendParametersData = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int,int,int)

        self.pushBtnOK.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.pusBtnCancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)

        self.hSliderOverlap.valueChanged.connect(self.lblOverlapValue.setNum)
        # self.hSliderSpeed.valueChanged.connect(self.lblSpeedValue.setNum)

        self.hSliderSpeed.valueChanged.connect(self.updateSpeedData)
        # self.hSliderOverlap.valueChanged.connect(self.updateOverlapData)


    def updateSpeedData(self):
        scaledValue = float(self.hSliderSpeed.value()) / 10  # type: float
        # self.lblSpeedValue.setText(str(self.hSliderSpeed.value()))
        print('value is: ')
        print(scaledValue, type(scaledValue))
        self.lblSpeedValue.setText(str(scaledValue))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppWindow()  # type: Instance of the Class
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, after editing all the data in the Dialog, when I press OK button once, the data is transferred but Dialog is not closed. On second press of OK button the dialog closes. What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: You call `dialogParameters.exec_()` twice, so it is shown twice.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro. I have corrected the same. Then how to print the value of dialog.exec_. Also, the print in function updateSpeedData in Class createParameterDialog is called even after the dialog values have been displayed in MainWindow. Print Data -----     "value is: 
3.469 <class 'float'>
Speed: 3.469, Rounds: 2, Overlap: 98 
3.469 <class 'float'>  "

Comment: Use `if dialogParameters.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:` and `print('Dialog Completed with ' + str(dialogParameters.result()))`.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that. Also, the print in function updateSpeedData in Class createParameterDialog is called even after the dialog values have been displayed in MainWindow. Print Data ----- "value is: 3.469 <class 'float'> Speed: 3.469, Rounds: 2, Overlap: 98 3.469 <class 'float'> "

Comment: What did you expect the code to do? Also, I don't see how this is related to your original question.